# Is the Beechcraft Bonanza Jaguar edition different from any other A36?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, beechcraft-bonanza

I've seen a few Beechcraft A36 Bonanzas with special Jaguar marketing. Some have special paint or interiors. During some hangar talk I've heard it said that the Jaguar edition is faster. Does it actually have any differences that impact performance?

Comment: From what I have read and discussed on the topic, the Jag version seems simply to be a paint job and upscale interior (not sure on the interior part). Unless Beech snuck in a 310hp 550 or 350hp TSIO the Jag should be just a dolled up A36. As far as I know, Beech only built the non-turbo A36with a 285hp 520 and then a 300hp 550, including the Jag model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@acpilot is right- the Jaguar version of Beechcraft Bonanza differs only in the paint job and interiors. [AOPA had run an article when the Jaguar versions were introduced](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/1999/may/pilot/a-star-is-born):

> Like the Jaguar edition of the Beech King Air C90B offered last year, the Bonanza and Baron will have specially outfitted interiors and unique paint schemes.
>
> ... Seats in the Jaguar airplane will use the same frames but have new cushions tailored to look like those found in the Jaguar Vanden Plas luxury car. ... tastefully wrapped the yokes in leather.
>
> On the outside, a special paint scheme has been designed to set the Jaguar airplanes apart from standard Bonanzas and Barons.

and also,

> The new soundproofing Beech plans for the Jaguar airplanes appears to work well in the rear of the airplane.

Looks like the only differences were the [paint and interiors designed by Jaguar specialists](http://www.avweb.com/news/newacft/182745-1.html):

> Jaguar Cars' automotive stylists designed the paint and interior for these packages. Inside, they applied more and finer hardwoods — including a polished Jag-logo inlay on the right yoke — better carpeting, and the finest leathers from Jaguar's own vendors. Outside, the Jag-edition Bonanzas ... get a distinctive four-color metal-flake paint scheme finished off with Jaguar Cars' stylized leaping-cat insignia leaping from the vertical stab and rudder.

These are the only differences and everything else is the same. The performance changes if any would come from these- which I doubt. Around the same time, the Continental engines were refined (they were the same 300 hp though), which might have made the aircraft *appear* different, though there are none.